# Microsoft Edge create File Object

Tags: javascript, microsoft-edge

I have a problem with creating File object in Microsoft Edge. In Chrome it works perfectly.

```
var generatedFile = new window.File(["Rough Draft ...."], "Draft1.txt", {type: "text/plain", lastModified: new Date()})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/mazhekin/wtnpa87o/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The file constructor isn't yet supported in Microsoft Edge. [View relevant caniuse page](http://caniuse.com/#feat=fileapi).

A possible workaround (which worked for me) is to use the Blob constructor. As described [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/documentation/dev-guide/html5/file-api/).

Comment: The linked page points to the  mdn input type page.

Comment: It looks like they may have fixed this issue: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File